# How to practice writing real Linux Device Drivers?

Tags: linux, header, kernel, device, drivers

I am a intermediate level programmer with a decent experience in Linux Kernel Programming. During my internship I was mostly involved in debugging the kernel and driver code. I recently finished studying the Kernel Development book by Robert Love. I am halfway through the Linux Device Drivers Book by Jonathan Corbet. But I am now faced with a troubling issue. None of these books teach me how to actually write *real* (Hardware) Device Drivers. the LDD3e book tells me how to write memory based software drivers and sysfs interfacing in which I'm pretty good at. So where do I start ? What are the requirements and how do I go about it ?

P.S: I have begun reading the book *'Essential Linux Device Drivers by Sreekrishnan Venkateswaran'*

Comment: I would study the source code of existing drivers in the linux kernel (in particular for hardware with available specs).

Comment: The drivers are too many and how do I know which hardware to use.

Comment: You should know the hardware that you have. Also, see http://kernelnewbies.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should DO it rather than just read it.

There is a great way to DO it first hand with fun.

Follow eudyptula challenge. Just got to eudyptula-challenge.org and do what they say. There are 20 tasks. After solving them you will not only know about kernel, but you would have done things with linux and kernel.

They says that they are using script to verify your drivers during challenge tasks, but I highly doubt it due to humorous and funny responses I get from them!

Comment: "Unfortunately right now the Eudyptula challenge is not accepting new applicants".